# I cannot connect to signalr

Tags: android, kotlin, signalr

I'm trying to connect to signalr but it says it failed. I am entering the correct URL,
I wanted to hide it in this code.Bağlantı başarısız. -> This means connection error in English.

Connection can be established with Postman

What is the solution to this?
Thank you in advance for your answers

```
class WebSocketActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var hubConnection: HubConnection

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_socket)

    connectToSignalR()
}

private fun connectToSignalR() {
    val hubUrl = "https://myurl" // SignalR sunucu URL'si

    hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(hubUrl)
        .withTransport(TransportEnum.WEBSOCKETS) // WebSockets veya LongPolling seçeneği
        .build()


    // "ReceiveMessage" adlı hub metodunu dinle
    hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage") { ->
        Log.e("SignalR", "Mesaj al")
    }

    hubConnection.onClosed { exception ->
        if (exception != null) {
            // Bağlantı hatası oluştu, exception içinde hatayı kontrol edebilirsiniz
            Log.e("SignalR", "Connection closed with error: ${exception.message}")
        }
    }

    // Bağlantıyı başlat
    try {
        hubConnection.start()
        if (hubConnection.connectionState == HubConnectionState.CONNECTED) {
            Log.d("SignalR", "Bağlantı başarıyla tamamlandı.")

            // "restaurantId" sorgu parametresini gönder
            val restaurantId = "oclv"
            hubConnection.send("restaurantId", restaurantId)
        } else {
            Log.e("SignalR", "Bağlantı başarısız.")
        }
    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("SignalR", "Bağlantı hatası: ${e.message}")
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Log.e("SignalR", "Bağlantı hatası: ${e.message}")
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    hubConnection.stop() // Bağlantıyı kapat
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also try this. You need asynchronous listening. I hope it works.

```
hubConnection.start().doOnComplete {
        Log.d("SignalR", "Bağlantı başarıyla tamamlandı.")
    }.doOnError {
        Log.e("SignalR", "Bağlantı başarısız.")
    }.subscribe()
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro, this was my job.